# Not getting any runtime errors from QGIS Plugin

Tags: qgis, qgis-plugins, debugging

I am working on developing QGIS plugin, but I don't get any errors (beside initial, for example when I try to import non existing class). My colleague gets window with error and message in Log Panel, but I get absolutely nothing in the same case. I tried most recent LTR and latest release of QGIS, but the problem persists in both. What can be the cause of this?

Comment: How are you developing it, do you have plugin reloader plugin installed? Do you reload the plugin after you make changes?

Comment: Yes, I have plugin reloader and I am reloading plugin. I also can push QgsMessageLog.logMessage, so I know that changes are made, but I just don't get errors. They just pass silently.

Comment: What is the error message your colleague gets?

Comment: psycopg2.errors.InsufficientPrivilege: permission denied for schema annot, but I can divide by zero and still not get any errors (tried that)